# invalid hook call useMemo inside a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a constant that I pass into a component. To reduce re-renders I would like to memo the constant, however I get a invalid hook call error. I am memoizing the constant inside a onClickHandler.

Before

```js
const handleOpen = (index?: number) => {
    const isNewUser = index === undefined;
    const user = index !== undefined ? form?.users?.[index] ?? {} :{});
}
```

After

```js
const handleOpen = (index?: number) => {
    const isNewUser = index === undefined;

    const user = useMemo(
      () => (index !== undefined ? form?.users?.[index] ?? {} : {}),
      [index]
    );
}
```

google, stackoverflow

Comment: 1. If it is a "constant", then it won't cause re-renders because it won't change - it is a constant. 2. Hooks can only be called at the top level of the functional component or inside another hook.

Comment: The user constant is then being passed as a prop to a component. Trust me, it’s this constant that’s causing re- renders

Comment: Is there a way to memo it?

Comment: Are you storing it in a state somewhere before passing it to the child component? Memo it from the component level variable. Or memo it inside the child component.

Answer (score 0):

**React Hooks should be not used within a nested function.**  
 For further info you refer [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) documentation. 
This approach is definitely not recommended.

Consider checking out `useRef` if it matches your use-case. Manipulating useRef doesn't cause re-render. You can checkout this  [link](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef) for futher info.

Comment: How would this be done with a use ref?

Comment: You will need to share the entire code and usecase to answer that.